# Concurrent login with identity server

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I have Identity Server 4 as a token issuer and have multiple microservices (resources) that are authorized using IdentityServerAuthentication. Currently Identity Server issues multiple tokens for a single user, and my api responds successfully on all the tokens. I want to restrict the user to only one token at a time each time after a new successful login on Ids; old sessions should be expired and Api should not respond on old tokens.

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options => 
    {   
        options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerUri"];
        options.EnableCaching = true;
        options.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.DiscoveryDocumentRefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

May Reference Tokens are what you are looking for.

[https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html#)

This allows you to instantly disable tokens.